# Selecting certain colums from a csv file

Tags: python, numpy

I'm having trouble selecting certain columns from a csv file. Any suggestions?

Here is my code.

```
import numpy
import csv

def load_metrics(filename):
    
    """A function to analyse and extract csv files"""
    
    data_list = []
    final_data = []
    with open(filename) as csvfile:
        
        file = csv.reader(csvfile)
        for row in file:
            data_list.append(row)
            
    for data in data_list:
        data_a = data[0:1]
        data_b = data[7:13]
        data_a.append(data_b)
        final_data.append(data_a)
        
    data = numpy.array(final_data)
    return data
```

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Format the code properly, and share the portion of the dataset. Also, list the expected behavior, and the trouble you are facing to read the CSV.

Comment: You should have included some basic example data and an example of how you call this function in the example, as well as an example of the expected output, so people here could test your code and see what you expected. However, it's clear what the function was supposed to do - you just risk that people make assumptions about your data that are wrong.

Comment: shorted: `data_list = list(file)`. But if you want to use only selected columns then you could keep `for`-loop and do select  when you read rows - `data_list.append( row[0:1] + row[7:13] )`

Answer (score 2):

Your code has several problems. In this line:

```
        data_a.append(data_b)
```

You probably expect `data[0:1]` and `data[7:13]` to be put together in a single list, instead of what actually happens, which is creating `[data[0], [data[7], data[8], .., data[12]]`. What you wanted there is:

```
        data_a.extend(data_b)
```

You do this one line at a time, collecting the results in a list of lists, and then turn this into a numpy array.

That's not impossible, but overly complicated. You could have also:

```
import numpy

def load_metrics(filename):
    with open(filename) as csvfile:
        file = csv.reader(csvfile)

        data = [[data[0], *data[7:13]] for data in file]

    return numpy.array(data)

result = load_metrics('data.csv')
print(result)
```

Or just using `numpy` alone:

```
import numpy

data = numpy.genfromtxt('data.csv', delimiter=',')
result = numpy.delete(data, range(1, 7), 1)

print(result)
```

(all this assuming your file has no column header)

As user @hpaulj correctly points out, even simpler (though perhaps a bit harder to understand):

```
import numpy

result = numpy.genfromtxt('data.csv', delimiter=',', usecols=[0, *range(7, 13)])

print(result)
```

Comment: `genfromtxt` also takes a `usecols` parameter.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using pandas:

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('yourfile.csv')

data = df.iloc[:, [0,1]+list(range(7,13))]

date_numpy = data.to_numpy() #convert to numpy
```

you can also select by column name; example:

```
df.loc[:, ['name', 'age']]
```

Comment: This answer isn't wrong, but is telling OP "use `pandas` instead of `numpy`" - `pandas` isn't needed for this problem, although it's not a bad tool to use. `numpy`'s `genfromtxt` can  do the job.

Comment: I agree, but I think it is shorter and easier to follow. @Grismar

Comment: If you read my answer using `numpy`, I have to disagree - the solution is literally two easy lines of `numpy` as well (see my answer). You can *prefer* `pandas`, but it's not shorter, and I wouldn't call it easier.

Comment: @Grismar Performance wise Pandas work faster on large sets! I am also not really in favor of the `delete` operation. it doesn't hurt keeping both answers doesn't hurt! Thanks for the nice genfromtxt solution, anyway!

Answer (score 0):

Firstl: It would be shorter to read all rows

```
data_list = list(file)
```

But if you want to use only selected columns then you could keep `for`-loop and do select when you read rows

```
data_list.append( row[0:1] + row[7:13] )
```

---

```
import csv
import numpy

def load_metrics(filename):
    
    data = []

    with open(filename) as csv_file:
        csv_reader = csv.reader(csv_file)

        for row in csv_reader:
            data.append( row[0:1] + row[7:13] )

    return numpy.array(data)
```